# Position divs side by side without using css float

Tags: html, css

I need to place a couple squares side by side using this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
.block{
height:20px;
width:20px;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
margin-right:3px;
}
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 <div class="block"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

but I am using one application named Corda to generate PDF out of the HTML,which does not support the css float property. Are there any other ways to achieve the same effect using other css properties? (Corda has only basic css tag support)

Answer (score 3):

You can use display:inline to get them next to one another.  display:inline-block will cause them to behave more like a standard `<div>` but its not supposed by ie7 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` instead of `div` attribute, which doesnt put line breaks

Comment: span is not a block level element and thus the break after will disappear, but the width and height of the element will also disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block;
/* Or */
display: table-cell;
```

are your best options. unfortunately, lower IEs won't like both.